# Making a history quiz card from an Access database

Tags: vba, ms-access

I want to make a card set with 4 unique history objects (like: Urbanization, Pope, Knight, Feudalism) on each card (to play the board game 30 seconds with a history theme and teach my students things the need to learn in a fun way). I already have an Access 2016 database with this information in it coupled with the time period each object is related to and several queries (to sort the object to time period). So I want to export it to Excel to make cards out of them. To do that I need to export the object to a specific column (b2). If come up with the following VB code (coupled to a button). Only when I run the code I get an error message:

> Compile error Expected End With

This is the code:

```
Option Compare Database

Private Sub cmdTransfer_Click()

    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
    Dim xlBook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim xlSheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim SQL As String
    Dim rs1 As DAO.Recordset

    SQL = "SELECT Begrip" & _
                "FROM Begrippen"

        Set rs1 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(SQL, dbOpenSnapshot)

        Set xlApp = Excel.Application
        xlApp.Visable = False
        Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("D:\30seconds.xlsx")
        Set xlSheet = xlBook.Worksheets(1)

        With xlSheet
            .Columns("B").ColumWidth = 20

            .Range("B2").CopyFromRecordset rs1
        end With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Martin, you need to include more details about what you have tried and what is going wrong. Please see [ask] and [mcve] for more info. Once you add example code we can try to help you debug.

Comment: i Updated my Question.

Comment: The error is quite clear, isn't it? You start a With block, but don't end it.

Comment: Also, use Option Explicit. https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/1107/vba-best-practices/3554/always-use-option-explicit#t=201607281607357211291

Answer (score 0):

Try to get rid of the with statement.

```
xlSheet.Columns("B").ColumWidth = 20
xlSheet.Range("B2").CopyFromRecordset rs1
```

And you should use `option explicit`